# Calling DOM objects using Java's ScriptEngine or WebEngine classes

Tags: java, javascript, javafx-2, scriptengine

Is it possible to modify html elements using the ScriptEngine or WebEngine classes from Java? I've tried the following:

```
/* theSite is a WebEngine object. Assume the id 'Email' is correct */
Element email=(Element) theSite.executeScript("document.getElementById('Email');");
email.setAttribute( "value", "navon.josh" );
```

I saw something like this in an example, but it didn't seem to work. I also tried this:

```
final ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
final ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName( "js" );
try {
    engine.eval( "document.getElementById( 'Email' ).value = 'navon.josh'" );
} catch( ScriptException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This also didn't work. Is it because the statement isn't linked to the WebEngine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access DOM model of html loaded into JavaFX 2 WebView you can use `WebEngine` API. E.g. here is an example of adding listener to HTML TextArea:

```
WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
  public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {

        // note next classes are from org.w3c.dom domain
        EventListener listener = new EventListener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event ev) {
                System.out.println(ev.getType());
            }
        };

        Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
        Element el = doc.getElementById("textarea");
        ((EventTarget) el).addEventListener("keypress", listener, false);
    }
  }
});
webEngine.loadContent("<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>");
```

Comment: When I try to test the code, I get an error that says, "The type ChangeListener is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Thread.State>".  Could that be a problem with my version of Java?

Comment: This is an import problem in your program not a version problem with Java.  Import `javafx.concurrent.Worker.State` rather than `Thread.State`.

Answer (score -2):

No.  The DOM is part of a browser and you don't have a browser.

Comment: So then there's no way to call HTML elements from the WebView?

Comment: If we're talking Android WebView, no, I couldn't find one.  You can do the opposite, though, and supply a Java object to Javascript in the page.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have been more specific. This has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: JavaFX 2 WebView is absolutely capable of providing DOM access.