# Java's ScriptEngine Local vs Global Scope and Delayed Declaration

Tags: java, scriptengine

I have a scenario where I am processing user provided templates that contain portions of JavaScript. I am using Java's `ScriptEngine` to evaluate those bits of JavaScript. I have various helper functions that I only wish to evaluate once (think of these helpers functions as loading something like `Underscore.js`).

Once this has been loaded I then loop through rows of data and process the template for each row - these templates may use any of the previously loaded helper functions. I am trying to process the rows in parallel as Java's `ScriptEngine.eval()` is quite slow in this scenario.

Anyone who looks at this over simplified SSCCE will know that I am getting the expected outcome that I have shown, as I am modifying a global object in a non thread safe way. In my example `sJsGlobal` is this global JavaScript. The global functions need access to various row specific bits of data, that I place within `obj`.

For `sJsGlobal` to successfully `eval()` it needs to know about `obj` or it will fail. In my SSCCE, each thread is updating the same global `obj` before calling a function. I am looking for a way for each global function to see a local `obj`. It is a Catch-22 situation, I need to define the variable for the global script to know it exists, but I want it to be of local significance.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import javax.script.*;

public class SSCCE {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sJsGlobal = new StringBuilder();
    sJsGlobal.append("var obj = {};");
    sJsGlobal.append("function get_row() { return \"Row is \" + obj.row }"); 

    ScriptEngine jsGlobal = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    jsGlobal.eval(sJsGlobal.toString());

    Bindings gB = jsGlobal.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    ArrayList<Future<String>> af = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      final int fi = i;
      af.add(es.submit(() -> {
        StringBuilder sJsLocal = new StringBuilder();
        sJsLocal.append("obj.row = " + fi + ";");
        sJsLocal.append("var x = get_row();");

        ScriptEngine jsLocal = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        ScriptContext sc = new SimpleScriptContext();
        Bindings lB = jsLocal.createBindings();
        lB.putAll(gB);
        sc.setBindings(lB, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
        jsLocal.setContext(sc);

        jsLocal.eval(sJsLocal.toString());
        return (String)jsLocal.get("x");
      }));
    }

    for (Future<String> f : af) {
      System.out.println("Returned -> " + f.get());
    }
    es.shutdown();
  }
}
```

This results in the following output where the rows are being overwritten as it isn't thread safe due to my use of this global `obj` variable. Even with a separate `ScriptEngineManager` and `ScriptEngine`. I need a way of settings the bindings so they don't interfere with other instances.

```
Returned -> Row is 4
Returned -> Row is 4
Returned -> Row is 4
Returned -> Row is 4
Returned -> Row is 8
Returned -> Row is 5
Returned -> Row is 6
Returned -> Row is 7
Returned -> Row is 8
Returned -> Row is 9
```

I could pass the row specific data into each function as variables, but this becomes very messy as my example doesn't do justice to the amount of data I need to exchange. The functions are also called by user scripts which makes this very difficult. I really want to find a way to redefine `obj` in each thread before I evaluate `sJsLocal`.

This all works fine if I process each row one after another without threading, but I am trying to speed this up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial, error and effort and reading lots of similar questions with no answers, I have come up with the following which seems to work and is documented here for anyone else who comes across this problem. This uses a common `ScriptEngine` with an individual `ScriptContext` per thread to provide isolation.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import javax.script.*;

public class SSCCE {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngine js = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    StringBuilder sJsGlobal = new StringBuilder();
    sJsGlobal.append("var obj = {};");
    sJsGlobal.append("function get_row() { return \"Row is \" + obj.row; }"); 
    CompiledScript jsLib = ((Compilable)js).compile(sJsGlobal.toString());

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    ArrayList<Future<String>> af = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      final int fi = i;
      af.add(es.submit(() -> {
        StringBuilder sJsLocal = new StringBuilder();
        sJsLocal.append("obj.row = " + fi + ";");
        sJsLocal.append("var x = get_row();");

        ScriptContext scLocal = new SimpleScriptContext();
        scLocal.setBindings(js.createBindings(), ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
        jsLib.eval(scLocal);
        js.eval(sJsLocal.toString(), scLocal);
        return (String)scLocal.getAttribute("x");
      }));
    }

    for (Future<String> f : af) {
      System.out.println("Returned -> " + f.get());
    }
    es.shutdown();
  }
}
```

This results in the following when run:

```
Returned -> Row is 0
Returned -> Row is 1
Returned -> Row is 2
Returned -> Row is 3
Returned -> Row is 4
Returned -> Row is 5
Returned -> Row is 6
Returned -> Row is 7
Returned -> Row is 8
Returned -> Row is 9
```